# Use of instrumentation for size of objects

Tags: java

I used the article http://www.devinline.com/2016/05/java-instrumentation-fundamental-part-1.html?m=1

I need to get size of query results.

But calling of

```
long sizeOfObject = InstrumentationAgent.findSizeOfObject(myvar);
```

returns the error

> Agent not initted.

I have the main method of class with throws `Exception`
Can you give a recommendation for right syntax?

Rev:
Agent code:

```
package org.h2.command;
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;
import java.lang.instrument.UnmodifiableClassException;

public class InstrumentationAgent {
    /*
     * System classloader after loading the Agent Class, invokes the premain
     * (premain is roughly equal to main method for normal Java classes)
     */
    private static volatile Instrumentation instrumentation;

    public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation instObj) {
        // instObj is handle passed by JVM
        instrumentation = instObj;
    }

    public static void agentmain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation instObj)
        throws ClassNotFoundException, UnmodifiableClassException {
    }

    public static long findSizeOfObject(Object obj) {
        // use instrumentation to find size of object obj
        if (instrumentation == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Agent not initted");
        } else {
            return instrumentation.getObjectSize(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

My invoking:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;
import org.h2.command.InstrumentationAgent;
import static java.lang.System.out;  

public class CacheOptimize {
    public long Size;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:file:D:/server/h2/exp1.h2.db", "sa", "sa");
        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs;
        rs = stat.executeQuery("select * from TAbles");
        Size = InstrumentationAgent.findSizeOfObject(rs);   
    }
    stat.close();
    conn.close();
}
```

Comment: Show your `MANIFEST.MF` and agent code

Comment: Added the nessasary code

Comment: Can anybody help?

Comment: Added an attempt to explain what is wrong and maven project which does what you want

Answer (score 3):

You either forgot to add `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` with entry

```
Premain-Class: org.h2.command.InstrumentationAgent
```

or running your application without `-javaagent:path/to/agent.jar`.

[Here](https://github.com/KetothXupack/stackoverflow-answers/tree/master/q39498765) you can find complete working example of how you can run start your application with agent.

You can also find more information regarding manifest entries and running agents in [official javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html).

**NOTE**

It seems like you are trying to get size of data which will be returned by `ResultSet` but not the amount of memory consumed by `ResultSet` object itself. The problem is that

```
size = InstrumentationAgent.findSizeOfObject(rs);
```

will be not the best approach since `ResultSet` only maintains a cursor to database row and does not store all results. However you can fetch all data using it and summarize sizes using `findSizeOfObject`. But last thing you should know is that [`Instrumentation#getObjectSize`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#getObjectSize(java.lang.Object)) may return inaccurate result

> Returns an implementation-specific approximation of the amount of storage consumed by the specified object. The result may include some or all of the object's overhead, and thus is useful for comparison within an implementation but not between implementations. The estimate may change during a single invocation of the JVM.